# Accessing KIE Workbench Git repository on OpenShift deployment

Tags: git, openshift, jbpm, sshd, minishift

I have KIE Workbench deployed on Minishift instance. I want to clone the repository.

First of all I know, I should make ssh port reachable. To do this I use the following command:

```
$ oc port-forward workbench-1-vfd6k 8001:8001
```

To check the port exposed as expected, I use 'telnet' and able to observe sshd working:

```
$ telnet localhost 8001
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-SSHD-CORE-1.6.0
```

So far, so good. However, actual cloning doesn't work:

```
$ git clone ssh://admin@localhost:8001/myrepo
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
Warning: Permanently added '[localhost]:8001' (DSA) to the list of known hosts.
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 127.0.0.1 port 8001: incorrect signature
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Does anybody know how to fix the issue?

Comment: Is your repo in `/` on the server side? As in `/myrepo.git`?

Comment: @VonC yes, but the problem appears before the repo name evaluates. I had stable envoronment before and if repo wasn't found, the error message is deffrent.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to

`<property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.ssh.algorithm" value="RSA"/`

per

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3362861

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it doesn't help. One more detail - it happens only on Minishift, I'm able to clone such repositories from OpenShift Orign cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The path should be something like /. In my case I did the following `git clone ssh://kieAdminUser@localhost:8001/myteam/Course-Scheduling`

Also make sure the user exists in the Application Realm, not the Management Realm